# Open Graph | Publish an Action | Using PHP for cURL instead of terminal

Tags: php, curl, publish, facebook-opengraph

I am new to the developing with the facebook platform.
I'm currently following the tutorial here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/

I am at step 4, under "Publish an action".

Where it wants me to copy the code snippet directly into the cURL terminal:

The only problem is while contacting my webhost technical support(1and1), they informed me that I was on a shared hosting plan and that I could not access the terminal directly and I would have to do this through a php script.

I don't know how to do this, can anyone please, please point me in the right direction!!

Here are the instructions facebook gives me:

Publish an Action

Publishing an action connects the user to the object you created. The Open Graph Dashboard page has a 'Get Code' link next to your action. This contains curl code snippets that you can copy into terminal and run directly.

Publishing an action involves making an HTTP POST to the me/[namespace]:[action_type] Graph API endpoint with the following parameters:

```
[object_type]: a link to a web page representing an object.
access_token: a valid user access_token with publish_actions permissions.
```

For example, sending a POST to:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook
       ?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

This will publish a cook action for the recipe corresponding to the provided OBJECT_URL. Replace OBJECT_URL with your web page URL.

Comment: To run BASH commands you can surround commands with the backtick operator and capture their return value. Offtopic but get a hosting company that allows you to SSH into your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [PHP's built-in cURL support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php), not terminal calls.

Answer (score 0):

I use 1and1 and I have ssh access.

contact them and ask them to alter your plan because it is achievable.

see here for more info: http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/secure_shell_access_ssh/index.html

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for my lack of knowledge, but what would SSH help me achieve? Would it allow me to pass commands directly to the terminal? Sorry I have absolutely no knowledge of php, although I'm starting to learn. BTW, I believe my plan let's me SSH, if i am correct.