# Open Graph Publish Action using PHP (lacking terminal and cURL)

Tags: facebook, post, action

I'm in a similar situation as : [this guy on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509114/open-graph-publish-an-action-using-php-for-curl-instead-of-terminal). I'm following this tutorial on facebook ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)) and on step 4. I need to publish an action on facebook. The tutorial says to run the following code in terminal:
POST  https://graph.facebook.com/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook
?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN


My server is hosted by Winhost and they don't support cUrl or Terminal use because the servers are shared. What can I do in PHP to post the action? Thanks for any help

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+do+a+post+request+in+php+without+cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your host if you need to use PHP to achieve posts as you will never be able to work with the Graph API to the best of your ability. For example, you will not be able to use the PHP SDK as it relies on cURL as well.

As the tutorial indicates in the end, you can achieve calls to Facebook via the JS SDK. Create a test page with the JS SDK loaded as shown in the tutorial and click the button to publish the action

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# [YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]: 
                  http://ogp.me/ns/apps/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]#">
  <title>OG Tutorial App</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="[YOUR_APP_ID]" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:recipe" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook',
        'post',
        { recipe: 'http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '[YOUR_APP_ID]', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
  </script>

  <h3>Stuffed Cookies</h3>
  <p>
    <img title="Stuffed Cookies" 
         src="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" 
         width="550"/>
  </p>

  <br>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```